# AppbarLayout inside a nested coordinator layout

Tags: android, android-coordinatorlayout, android-appbarlayout

Wanted to know if there is way for outer appbar to scroll when nested appbar is being scrolled.

Outer Coordinator layout -> appbar layout,
Tab layout

Inside first tab -> nested coordiantor layout -> appbar layout

when appbar inside nested coordiantor layout is scrolled, I want the outside appbar layout to scroll also.